# how to insert into DB from XMl using python multithreading?

Tags: python, xml, multithreading

Could someone please advice me what are the possible ways with python multithreading? 
I have one xml file (163 MB). My task is required to

1. read that xml file
2. insert the data into a DB ( many tables)
3. record the count of inserted rows in a log file

I already have python code that reads an xml file that does the above 1,2 and 3 steps. Actually, I want to speed up that process using multithread. I don't know how to start work on.

Here's XML structure.

```
<Content id="359366">
    <Title>This title</Title>
    <SortTitle>sorting</SortTitle>
    <PublisherEntity id="2003">ABC Publishing Group</PublisherEntity>
    <Publisher>ABC Publishing Group</Publisher>
    <Imprint>Revell</Imprint>
    <Language  code = "en">English</Language>
    <GeoRight>
        <GeoCountry  code = "WW" model = "Distribution">World</GeoCountry>
        </GeoRight>
    <Format type = "Adobe EPUB eBook">
        <Identifier type = "DRMID">xxx-xxx-xx</Identifier>
        <Identifier type = "ISBN">1234567</Identifier>
        <SRP currency = "SGD">18.89</SRP>
        <WholesaleCost currency = "SGD">11.14</WholesaleCost>
        <OnSaleDate>01 Sep 2010</OnSaleDate>
        <MinimumSoftwareVersion number="1.x">Adobe Digital Editions</MinimumSoftwareVersion>
        <DownloadFileName>HouseonMalcolmStreet9781441213877</DownloadFileName>
        <SecurityLevel value="ACS4">Adobe Content Server 4</SecurityLevel>
        <ContentFileSize>473923</ContentFileSize>
        <DownloadUrl>http://xxx.xx.com/</DownloadUrl>
        <DownloadIDType>CRID</DownloadIDType>
        <DrmInfo>
            <Copy>
                <Enabled>1</Enabled>
                <Selections>2</Selections>
                <Interval type = "Days">7</Interval>
            </Copy>
            <Print>
                <Enabled>1</Enabled>
                <Selections>20</Selections>
                <Interval type = "Days">7</Interval>
            </Print>
            <Lend>
                <Enabled>0</Enabled>
            </Lend>
            <ReadAloud>
                <Enabled>0</Enabled>
            </ReadAloud>
            <Expires>
                <Enabled>0</Enabled>
                <Interval type = "Days">-1</Interval>
            </Expires>
        </DrmInfo>
        </Format>
    <Creator rank="1" id="923710"> 
        <Name>name</Name>
        <FileAs>Kelly, Leisha</FileAs>
        <Role id="aut">Author</Role>
    </Creator>
    <SubTitle>A Novel</SubTitle>
    <Edition></Edition>
    <Series></Series>
    <Coverage></Coverage>
    <AgeGroup></AgeGroup>
    <ContentType></ContentType>
    <PublicationDate>09/01/2010</PublicationDate>
    <ShortDescription>description</ShortDescription>
    <FullDescription>full desc</FullDescription>
    <Image type = "Cover Image">http://xxx.xx.jpg</Image>
    <Image type = "Thumbnail Image">http://xxx.xx.jpg</Image>
    <Subject code="FIC000000">Fiction</Subject>
    <Subject code="FIC014000">Historical Fiction</Subject>      
</Content>
```

Here's existing python code [download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48001424/test.py).

Comment: I'd suggest that you profile your current code and work out how long different aspects are taking. I don't think that multithreading will necessarily speed the task up.

Comment: Thank you. I posted xml structure and current code file

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look through your code. I don't think that multithreading is the answer to your problems.

- Not all xml libraries are equal, `lxml` is a python interface to `libxml2`, which is written in C and the fastest I've used.
- Consider, if you haven't already, which operations are comparitively expensive time-wise. File operations are expensive compared to memory access. Each call to a database is expensive. Downloading things from the internet is expensive.
- I don't know what database and db interface you're using, but you should **really** use built-in parameterisation instead of your sanitizing functions.

I'd recommend re-structuring your code to use a batch-processing approach:

- Process the entire xml file extracting the data you need into a python data structure.
- Don't use separate files in the filesystem as part of your processing or caching. Try to avoid writing something to a file that you want to read later as part of the same job.
- Pre-cache your table lookups e.g. create a dictionary of `select name,id from table` instead of 100s of calls to `select id from table where name=%s`.
- Determine what foreign key table entries need creating in one go and create them all in one go, updating your `id/name` cache.
- Group database updates into `executeMany` calls if available.
- If you need to tidy rows from tables where they are no longer used as a foreign key, do it at the end, with a single SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't split reading in XML, from what I understand, but what you can do, is maybe depending on your XML structure and DB structure parallelize inserts into the database. Unfortunately without seeing XML and DB structure, also without knowing constraints of the database (like, for instance keeping order of the xml records vs auto_increment id's) - it's very difficult to advise you on some solution that would work for you in your particular situation.